# Is it possible to have a branch of code conditionally be compiled in C++?

Tags: c++11, metaprogramming, boost-mpl

Title says it all really. Sample code which illustrates the spirit of the affaire:

```
if( std::is_constructible<T, unsigned long>::value )
{
    unsigned long identity = collection.rbegin()->first + 1;
    std::shared_ptr<T> newObject(new T(identity));

    collection.insert( identity , newObject );
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The D language has this as static if, and DM C++ has this as an extension. It's not part of standard C++ though.

Comment: The optimizer would remove the useless branch....

Comment: Yes, but not with that syntax.  Search "tag dispatching".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tag dispatch.

```
template<class T>
bool foo_impl(std::true_type){
    unsigned long identity = collection.rbegin()->first + 1;
    std::shared_ptr<T> newObject(new T(identity));
    collection.insert( identity , newObject );
    return true;
}

template<class T>
bool foo_impl(std::false_type){
    return false;
}

template<class T>
bool foo(){
    return foo_impl<T>(std::is_constructible<T, unsigned long>());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the `if` statement can be determined at compile time, I'd expect the compiler to be smart and optimize it directly, just as if you had something like

```
if ( true ) {
    // Some code
}
else {
    // Anything here any decent compiler will ignore.
}
```

Another option is to wrap the behaviour you want in a function, and use `std::enable_if`:

```
template <typename T, typename = typename enable_if<is_constructible<T, int>::value>::type>
bool foo() {
    return true;   
}

template <typename T, typename = typename enable_if<!is_constructible<T, int>::value>::type>
bool foo() {
    return false;
}

// ...

return foo<T>();
```

Example: http://ideone.com/sgNVr5

Yet another option is to specialize on the boolean value:

```
template <bool b> bool foo();

template <>
bool foo<true>(){
    return true;
}

template <>
bool foo<false>() {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't help if one of your branches doesn't compile if the condition is false, which I imagine the author was getting at. Of course an optimizing compiler should be able to do trivial branch elimination like that.

Comment: Yes, this is more about syntactical sugar than it is about dead code stripping. The branch that is false at compile time also breaks the build at compile time. Tag dispatching seems to be what I was looking for.

Comment: @MB. The two template options I presented should not break your build, as the compiler will only instantiate the branch which is selected at compile time, ignoring the other. This is exactly the use case for std::enable_if, for example.